# Android 12 target SDK Application does not install on devices lower than Android 12

Tags: android

I create a New Android Studio Project.
Changed the following:
compileSdkVersion("android-S")
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion("S")

The application does not install on any device other than Android 12 device. Can anyone please tell me what am i doing wrong?

Comment: I upgrade targetSdkVersion to 31 and it stopped working on android 12. please help me out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74502338/parsing-the-package-issue-in-react-native

Answer (score 2):

> The application does not install on any device other than Android 12 device

That is perfectly normal at this point in the release process. Once we can start using `compileSdkVersion 31` instead of `compileSdkVersion 'android-S'` (and the equivalent for `targetSdkVersion`), then your apps will install normally on older devices.

And, to anticipate your next question... my hope is that they will "flip the switch" on this with Beta 3 here in July, but it might not be until the August update.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the update. I will be waiting for the update from Google side.

Answer (score 0):

**App isn't installed** error message while launching the app.

When targeting SDK version 31, then you need to add **android: exported** in the manifest for the activity tag which uses intent filters.

Please refer the doc:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element?authuser=1#exported

Comment: after adding it for every activity, service and receiver build is still not installing what should I do

Answer (score 0):

Note: On your launcher activity the `android:exported` tag needs to be set to true, otherwise the system won’t be able to start your app.

Answer (score -1):

for this please set `compileSdkVersion 30` and `targetSdkVersion 30` in Gradle file, it will work below the android 12 version device

Comment: I want to use the build with Target and Compile version S as i want to test the changes and make sure my build is compatible with Android 12

Comment: So we have another error in build : One or more plugins require a higher Android SDK version.
Fix this issue by adding the following to D:\work\customersProject\mrantick\MrAntikFlutter\android\app\build.gradle:
android {
  compileSdkVersion 33
  ...
}